# Aspose - PDF to Image (DotNetCore 2.1) - ERROR:region.c:1155:GdipCombineRegionPath: assertion failed: (region->bitmap)

Tags: .net-core, aspose.pdf

I get the following error when trying to convert a PDF page to an image.
ERROR:region.c:1155:GdipCombineRegionPath: assertion failed: (region->bitmap)

**Project Setup:**

- Aspose.Pdf Version: 18.6.0
- Framework: .NET Core 2.1
- Type: Console Application
- Docker container used: microsoft/dotnet:2.1.0-runtime

**Source PDF file**

- Size: 181 KB
- Page count: 4

Sample code:

```
public ImageData GenerateImage(byte[] pdfData, int pageNo)
{
    var imageStream = new MemoryStream();
    var pdfMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(pdfData);
    var pdfDocument = new Document(pdfMemoryStream);
    Resolution resolution = new Resolution(300);
    var pageToPrint = pdfDocument.Pages[pageNo];
    PngDevice pngDevice = new PngDevice(resolution);

    //This line causes the error
    pngDevice.Process(pageToPrint, imageStream );
}
```

Notes:
This works fine on a Windows machine but produces the error on a Linux 64bit Docker container.

Please see this link for the actual crash dump from the container: [Aspose Forum Question](https://forum.aspose.com/t/pdf-to-image-dotnetcore-2-1-error-region-cgdipcombineregionpath-assertion-failed-region-bitmap/178516)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We have already replied to same query posted by you over Aspose forum. Kindly follow up in respective thread. **PS:** I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Hi @FarhanRaza,
I have responded accordingly on the Aspose forum.

Comment: Thank you for the acknowledgement. We will get back to you after investigating the scenario in our environment.